# Excel VBA Run time Error 424: Object Required

Tags: excel, vba

I am totally new in VBA and coding in general, I'm trying to get data from cells from the same workbook if the condition is met to paste in another book.

I am getting this error when trying to get values entered in excel cells:

```
Run Time Error '424' object required
```

When I'm pressing the debug button it takes to the first line and highlights it. I am not able to recognize why it is happening? Also when in watch window it shows a=0.

The code is

```
Sub copycells()
    a = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sale").Cells(Row.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To a
    If Worksheets("Sale").Cells(i, 6).Value = "Parmesh" Then
    Worksheets("Sale").Row(i).copy
    Workbooks("Source.xlsx").Worksheets("Billdetails").Activate
    b = Workbooks("Source.xlsx").Worksheets("Billdetails").Cells(Row.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Workbooks("Source.xlsx").Worksheets("Billdetails").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
    ActivateSheet.Paste
    Worksheets("Sale").Activate
    End If
    Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Workbooks("Purchase.xlsx").Worksheets("Sale").Cells(1, 1).Select
    End Sub
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGMTP.png]

Answer (score 1):

## Option Explicit: Your Friend

That should teach you to always use `Option Explicit`. If you had been using it the following might have happened (`Compile error: Variable not defined`):

[image]

After OK:

[image]

you see that something is wrong with `Row`.

After changing to `Rows` another `Compile error: Variable not defined`. After OK:

[image]

you see that something is wrong with `a =`.

After adding `Dim a As Long` another `Compile error: Variable not defined`. After OK:

[image]

you see that something is wrong with `i`.

After adding `Dim i As Long` another `Compile error: Variable not defined`. After OK:

[image]

You see something is wrong with `Row` again.

After changing to `Rows` another `Compile error: Variable not defined`. After OK:

[image]

you see that something is wrong with `b =`.

After adding `Dim b As Long` another `Compile error: Variable not defined`. After OK:

[image]

you see that something is wrong with `ActivateSheet`.

After changing to `ActiveSheet` finally a `Run-time error`:

[image]

and after `Debug`:

[image]

`Row` looks suspicious again.

After changing to `Rows` another `Run-time error`:

[image]

and after `Debug`:

[image]

you see that something is wrong with `ActiveSheet.Paste`, especially `Paste`.

After changing to `ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial` another `Run-time error`:

[image]

and after `Debug`:

[image]

you see something is wrong with `Worksheets("Sale").Activate`.

Since Source.xlsx is active you consider changing to `Workbooks("Purchase.xlsx").Worksheets("Sale").Activate` and everything's finally OK. Or is it?

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub copycells()
    Dim a As Long
    Dim b As Long
    Dim i As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sale")
        a = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To a
            If .Cells(i, 6).Value = "Parmesh" Then
                .Rows(i).Copy
                With Workbooks("Source.xlsx").Worksheets("Billdetails")
                    b = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
                    .Cells(b + 1, 1).PasteSpecial
                End With
            End If
        Next
        ' If Purchase.xlsx and ThisWorkbook are the same then use the following:
        '.Cells(1).Select
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ' If Purchase.xlsx and ThisWorkbook are not the same then use the following:
    'Workbooks("Purchase.xlsx").Worksheets("Sale").Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub


' Assuming that you need only values and that "Thisworkbook" is "Purchase.xlsx"
Sub copyCellsValues()

    Const SourceBook As String = "Source.xlsx"
    Const SourceSheet As String = "Billdetails"
    Const MainSheet As String = "Sale"
    Const MainColumn As Long = 6
    Const Criteria As String = "Parmesh"

    Dim Sale As Worksheet
    Dim Bill As Worksheet
    Dim a As Long
    Dim b As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set Sale = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(MainSheet)
    Set Bill = Workbooks(SourceBook).Worksheets(SourceSheet)

    a = Sale.Cells(Sale.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    b = Bill.Cells(Bill.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    For i = 2 To a
        If Sale.Cells(i, MainColumn).Value = Criteria Then
            Bill.Rows(b).Value = Sale.Rows(i).Value
            b = b + 1
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it seems you need to declare missed variable:

```
Sub copycells()
    Dim a as Integer
    Dim b as Integer
    a = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sale").Cells(Row.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To a
      If Worksheets("Sale").Cells(i, 6).Value = "Parmesh" Then
         Worksheets("Sale").Row(i).copy
         Workbooks("Source.xlsx").Worksheets("Billdetails").Activate
         b = Workbooks("Source.xlsx").Worksheets("Billdetails").Cells(Row.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
         Workbooks("Source.xlsx").Worksheets("Billdetails").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
        ActivateSheet.Paste
        Worksheets("Sale").Activate
     End If
   Next
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Workbooks("Purchase.xlsx").Worksheets("Sale").Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```

Also, you may try to use the `Set` operator.

Anyway, it is not clear what property or method gives an error. So, I'd recommend breaking the chain of property and method calls:

```
a = Workbooks("Purchase.xlsx").Worksheets("Sale").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
```

Just declare separate lines of code where a single property or method will take its place. For example:

```
Dim workbk as Excel.Workbook
Dim worksht as Excel.Worksheet

Set workbk = Workbooks("Purchase.xlsx")
Set worksht = workbk.Worksheets("Sale")
```

Following that way, you will be able to find the problematic call.